# Why will Ucanaccess not delete my records?

Tags: java, ucanaccess

I can connect to my access database and select, insert records etc. I am now trying to delete records and as far as I can see I am using the correct syntax. I have followed just about every tutorial I can find and they are not doing anything different that I can see.

```
String deleteSql = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE sometext=? or sometext=?";

ps = module.getSupportConnection().prepareStatement(deleteSql);
ps.setString(1,"four");
ps.setString(2,"five");

int rs = ps.executeUpdate();
System.out.println(rs);
```

I have tried it without using int rs = .. but I used it just to see what the output was and it returns '2' which is what I was expecting as there are two records that meet the criteria used. It just wont delete the records and I cant see why. I dont get any errors when running the code. I appreciate this may not be a ucanaccess issue per se.

Comment: How do you check if the records were deleted?

Comment: I opened the database and checked the table

Comment: See if closing **ps** (as in: `ps.close();`) and perhaps even the connection (if that didn't work) **commits** the change. Is **connection.setAutoCommit()** set to **true**, for example: `conn.setAutoCommit(true);`? If not then you may need to **commit** the change after the **executeUpdate()**, for example: `ps.executeUpdate(); conn.commit();`. If you have MS Access open while running your java app then you may need to close and reopen MS Access to see the change.

Comment: That did the trick - conn.commit(); None of the tutorials said that. Many thanks